# How to start CRUD(Create,Delete,Update,Delete)/routing with FuelPhp framework after downloading Zip file of FuelPhp framework?

Tags: orm, frameworks, crud, fuelphp

I want to perform CRUD (create, read , update , delete) operation with FuelPhp framework from scratch. I just download the FuelPhp package and run it on  "http://localhost:3773/fuelphp/public/ "
now anyone help please What to do next for simple CRUD operation With ORM or without ORM.?

Comment: and what will be the Directory structure for it???

Comment: I am sorry, but you won't get answers for this kind of questions. You should ask specific questions here, not general "How to CRUD" ones.

Comment: I'm working on some free project based on FuelPHP. I think it is good enough for an example about CRUD.
https://github.com/OkveeNet/fuel-start

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you're probably new to web development. Are you following a tutorial somewhere? Do you have a proper development environment set up? Did you follow ALL of the instructions on how to set up your fuel setup at: [Fuelphp.com](http://fuelphp.com/docs/installation/instructions.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Also, look into Oil, it can generate all required files for you, from a migration to create the table to the model and controller needed for CRUD.

Comment: I am trying to use FuelPHP to build a small CRUD type of application. Very simple. Just a page where a user can enter Name, Address, City, Zip, etc... I need to be able to retrieve that info from Mongo and display it on page. Does anybody have some basic Fuel/Mongo application that they can share with me? Let me look at how you made the View, Controller and Model for Mongo, instead of MySQL?.can somebody show me how to convert the standard Oil scaffold from MySQL to Mongo